# Why my xlabel, ylabel and title are not displayed after a scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I'm setting up a filtering tool in Python. I want to plot some data based on others but I'm facing a problem with my scatter plots. In fact, the data are displayed but not the figure title, the x-axis label or the y-axis label. 
Could someone explain my error please? 
Thank you in advance.

```
x_text = str(self.comboBox1.currentText())
y_text = str(self.comboBox2.currentText())

x_data = self.data.getData(x_text)
y_data = self.data.getData(y_text)

if x_data is not None and y_data is not None : 
    if x_text =="Cycles":
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax = plt.subplot(111, facecolor= "lightgrey")
        for x,y in zip(x_data, y_data):
            if isinstance(y, list):
                ax.scatter([x]*len(y),y,marker = 'o',color="chocolate")
            else:
                ax.scatter(x,y,marker = 'o', color="teal")
        ax.set_title("Before filtering")
        #ax.set_xlabel(x_text)
        #ax.set_ylabel(y_text)
        ax.grid(True)
        fig.text(0.03,0.5 ,y_text, va='center', rotation = 'vertical', fontsize=12) #va : vertical alignement
        fig.text(0.5 ,0.03,x_text, ha='center',  fontsize=12)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Your x and y labels are commented out?

Comment: I commented them out to try with figure.text but both of them are not working. I'm using Python 3.7.0.

Comment: Typo? `set_tilte` should be `set_title`

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Check that you've corrected DavidGs comment, if not please construct a minimal example we can run, such that we can reproduce the error.